# Unable to predict floating values using svm in python

Tags: python, regression, svm

When I try to implement a simple svm regression model in python, I'm able to predict integer values, but prediction of floating values is not working.

Code:

```
from sklearn import svm
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("a.csv", dtype=None, delimiter=',') 
print data 
X=data[:,0:1]
y=data[:,1]
clf =svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y) 
m=clf.predict([1.2])
print m
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svm3.py", line 10, in <module>
    clf.fit(X, y) 
  File "/home/narayan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 151, in fit
  y = self._validate_targets(y)
 File "/home/narayan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 515, in _validate_targets
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "/home/narayan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 173, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
ValueError: Unknown label type: array([ 3.6,  6.6,  9.9])
```

CSV file data :

```
[[ 1.2  3.6]
[ 2.2  6.6]
[ 3.3  9.9]]
```

Comment: use `svm.SVR` instead of `svm.SVC` for regression problems.

Comment: the reason why svm.SVC runs for integer values is that each integer in the set of test values is treated as a label. In that case, you are doing a classification task. However, if you want to perform a regression, SVC won't do the job. As for why SVR didn't work, we have to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from sklearn for SVR

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> X = [[0, 0], [2, 2]]
>>> y = [0.5, 2.5]
>>> clf = svm.SVR()
>>> clf.fit(X, y) 
SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.1, gamma='auto',
    kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
>>> clf.predict([[1, 1]])
array([ 1.5])
```

See if this chunk of code runs for you.